# What's wrong with this regex? (using '.')

Tags: regex, f#

I wrote the following code in F# :

```
let regexSymbol = new Regex(@"\b\}|\.\b")
if (Regex.IsMatch(".", regexSymbol.ToString())) then
    printfn "symbol0"
```

But it doesn't print anything..

I'd like the regex to represent only strings that are exactly "}" or "." , without any following or preceding characters on the same line.
Anyone knows how I should change it please?

Thanks.. :)

Comment: Are those a few chained ors `|`? Consider using a _set_ to make it more readable...

Comment: @K-ballo I made it more readable now. Anyone?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the treatment of the word boundaries?  Which periods and right braces do you want to match?  And which exactly do you _not_ want to match?

Comment: @RayToal I editted the question :)

Comment: Oh, then on a line by itself?  If so, see @raina770w's answer.  If by no characters you mean it is okay to have _whitespace_, but no printable characters surrounding the brace or period, then you will need `@"(^|\s)[}.]($|\s)"`

Comment: `\s+`, perhaps. ) Or just `^\s*[whatever]\s*$`, actually would prefer this option.

Comment: I doubt this is anything specific to F#. You probably want to look at good regex tools to make sure you've got the right expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to match strings that way, you'd use beginning-of-string and end-of-string anchors:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
let regexSymbol = new Regex("^[}.]$") // in this case verbatim is not required
if (regexSymbol.IsMatch(".")) then printfn "Matched! :)" else printfn "Not matched... :("
if (regexSymbol.IsMatch("}.")) then printfn "Matched! :)" else printfn "Not matched... :("
```

This prints "Matched" at the first line, and "Not Matched" at the second.

But isn't it better just to check whether or not this string equal to "}" and '.'? Sorry, just starting exploring F#.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it :)
I have too many optional symbols to try for each an every string..

Comment: Well, that's truly weird: I've updated answer with the full code, which just works - '}.' is not matched. Could you show your code then? There should be a difference, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what a "." isn't considered a word boundary.   So \b" matches 'A"', but not '."'.

Comment: Thanks! How can I change it to recognize "." but not ".a." for example?